# how to make a custom current position button react-native-maps

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im using Expo and react-native-maps in my app. Added a jump button to my position:

```
            <MapView
                provider="google"
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 56.824,
                    longitude: 60.621,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                showsMyLocationButton={true}
            />
```

Button is displayed on the screen, but how can I move it or change it somehow?

Comment: same problem here, I want to move the button to bottom left corner and also i want to perform a function when user click on it, any solution you found?